# Is azure java sdk compatibile with azure gov cloud?

Tags: azure-java-sdk

https://github.com/azure/azure-libraries-for-java
Will the the azure java sdk work seamlessly for gov cloud as well? Are there any feature differences that need to be taken care of to use the SDK for gov cloud? Are there any API and feature differences that are not supported by the SDK for gov cloud?

Answer (score 0):

The big issue that I have with Azure GOV is that some features are not turned on yet in Azure. But with the Java SDK you should be just fine and stay away from the features that are not active in Azure GOV.